# Python TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects when trying to print

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, typeerror, calculator

I am running into this problem while trying to make a calculator, that takes time in seconds and gives an output of time in minutes:seconds, and it makes this error

[image: error]

This is my code:

```
timeInSeconds = 1823
timeInMinutes = timeInSeconds / 60
timeInRest = timeInSeconds % 60

str(timeInMinutes)
str(timeInRest)

print("Your time in minutes and seconds is " + timeInMinutes + ":" + timeInRest)
```

Comment: simply write this, print("Your time in minutes and seconds is " + str(timeInMinutes) + ":" + str(timeInRest)), or you need to store the str converted int values back to that var. here just casting to int will not store result to the org variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to reassign the new values:

```py
timeInSeconds = 1823
timeInMinutes = timeInSeconds / 60
timeInRest = timeInSeconds % 60

timeInMinutes = str(timeInMinutes)
timeInRest = str(timeInRest)

print("Your time in minutes and seconds is " + timeInMinutes + ":" + timeInRest)
```

Basically doing this :

```py
str(timeInMinutes)
```

Does not mean your TimeInMinutes variable is now a string. You have to reassign it like so :

```py
timeInMinutes = str(timeInMinutes)
```

I believe this is what you meant to do.

---

**However**, it could be useful to keep the int values for later. If that's the case, you could just create new variables like so :

```py
timeInMinutesStr = str(timeInMinutes)
timeInRestStr = str(timeInRest)

print("Your time in minutes and seconds is " + timeInMinutesStr + ":" + timeInRestStr)
```

Or, you could just convert the values directly in the print, to avoid having to assign new variables that you might not use later :

```py
print("Your time in minutes and seconds is " + str(timeInMinutes) + ":" + str(timeInRest))
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
print("Your time in minutes and seconds is " + timeInMinutes + ":" + timeInRest)
```

To

```
print("Your time in minutes and seconds is " + str(timeInMinutes) + ":" + str(timeInRest))
```